# PEP 8 and list comprehension

Tags: python

I seem to have hit a bit of a problem with PEP 8.

I am using list comprehension which is longer than 79 characters long. So my text editor is screaming at me to do something about it, and it's an eye soar to look at when coding.

[image]

```
return [(i['user_id'], i['id']) for i in j['collection'] if i and i['user_id']]
```

So, I attempt to break the line, but now it complains my line break is for visual purposes.

[image]

```
return [(i['user_id'], i['id']) for i in j['collection']
    if i and i['user_id']]
```

What's a man to do in such a pickle?

**Edit:** Based on the answers, I opted for readability over list comprehension in this case, and now it makes more sense to the reader:

```
tracks = set()

for track in json['collection']:
    if track and track['user_id']:
        tracks.add((track['user_id'], track['id']))
```

Comment: Get a more reasonable editor?

Comment: Try breaking the line before the for? That's usually what I do. I think it's more readable that way anyways.

Comment: Don't be a slave to the guide. [RHettinger's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M) from this PyCon very relevant.
Specifically: don't *harm* readability for the purpose of sticking to a guide. You can configure your editor and local lint configs to allow 100 or 120-char lines, 80 is ridiculous.

Comment: i truly do not understand the resistance people like @tzaman have to the 80-character limit.  that rule is one of the most important style rules out there.  nothing is less readable than a script or module with tons of wrap-around lines.  even if you have a large monitor, keeping lines to 80-characters allows you to have multiple files open next to each other.

Comment: I actually enjoy the 80-char character limit. Usually when a line is too long it means I need to take a look at what I'm doing because chances are things need a little refactoring.

Comment: 80 characters is the standard line length for the same reason that CRLF is the standard Windows line break, QWERTY is the standard keyboard layout, and paper is the standard material for books: history.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using pep8 common sense applies. If you can't fit a line of logic within 80 character it is almost always a sign that this line has to be rewritten. And it is true in this case as I can't for one even start to try to comprehend what is that line supposed to do.

But if you move it to a much more readable format then not only your line count will go up, but also your readability level, leaving you a lot of place for proper variable names like `user` instead of `i`. This will make your own maintenance in the future much easier, not to mention if someone else ever have to look at it.

So to put this example into actual code, that is what I would do with it (with a nice function wrap to make the sample much easier to read!):

```
j = {'collection': [{'id': 1, 'user_id': 1}]}

def get_qualified_users(users):
    qualified_users = []
    for user in users:
        if user and user['user_id']:
            qualified_users.append((user['user_id'], user['id']))
    return qualified_users

print(get_qualified_users(j['collection']))
```

You can easily copy/paste it into your interpetor to see that it works. And more than that - it is extremely easy to maintain and follow, with clear api encapsulated in a sealed function.

Comment: I often struggle with list comprehensions for this reason. Many times I've gone back to code and scratched my head for a few minutes figuring out what they do. Especially when they get more complex.

Comment: @LOLKAT then why do you embrace them? Drop the shackles, rework that code, make it better!

Comment: @LOLKAT I've updated the answer with a code sample for what I mean, about time to wrap this question ;).

Comment: You're turning a simple list comprehension into a six-line function that must be looked up _elsewhere_. I'd agree that extracting a function makes sense **if** this code appears more than once, but if that's not the case this is needless cognitive overhead.

Comment: @tzaman actually my solution takes less lines than yours when used and is much cleaner than any comprehension. It, in essence, replaces the whole one liner with `get_qualified_users(j['collection'])`, that is all to it. And who cares that you have to first define a function in appropriate file? Are you trying to say that having that definition, in another file, in encapsulated function, is a bad thing, because in order to look up its definition I have to navigate to it? You sir cannot be serious, and I hope that you work for my competitiors!

Comment: I modified my question to reflect the answer. 5 lines including the space, based on this answer. Granted it wasn't the answer to my question, but I do feel clarity in code is just as important.

Comment: It does, but `get_qualified_users` doesn't indicate what it's _actually doing._ Which is a trivial one-liner in the first place; I actually prefer the original line to any of my suggestions -- just don't be such a stickler about 80 chars, problem solved. 
Being able to see what's really happening directly at the site is **valuable**; your way doesn't show that there's a tuple of `(id, user_id)` being returned without having to look it up.

Comment: @LOLKAT that does end up nice looking. Meaningful variable names help a ton!

Comment: @tzaman then the question is - why should you care what does the API do inside? I certainly do not, when I pass iterable of `users` to `get_qualified_users` then I know that it will return me: qualified users.  Only time when I have to concern myself with how it works is if it doesn't work as it claims to, and when that happens then having it wrapped in function makes it a lot easier to debug and test out (not to mention proper testing as you go along with help of Behaviour/Unit testing frameworks). While nasty one liners are just that - nasty.

Comment: It's not a list of users though; it's a list of ID pairs. So at the very least you need to name it better. And I need to know what it's returning because I'm going to be _doing something_ with the returned values. I'm all for fluent programming, but you can certainly take it too far. I very much like the compromise solution OP arrived at at the end.

Answer (score 8):

if you want to stick strictly to pep8 then the hanging indent is your friend.

```
return [
    (i['user_id'], i['id'])
    for i in j['collection']
    if i and i['user_id']]
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to indent the second line properly:

```
return [(i['user_id'], i['id']) for i in j['collection']
        if i and i['user_id']]
```

[Confirmed](http://pep8online.com/s/RXxw0EMZ) with *PEP8 online*, but let me know whether it works for you as well.

Personally, I dislike expression and source together but the condition separate. I'd rather clearly see the expression alone, not the condition. Highlight what you get. So I would do one of these:

```
return [(i['user_id'], i['id'])
        for i in j['collection'] if i and i['user_id']]

return [(i['user_id'], i['id'])
        for i in j['collection']
        if i and i['user_id']]
```

Clarification: This is how I'd *indent/break*. I didn't consider the variable names, as I just wanted to give a direct answer and explain what the PEP8 error was and how to fix it, because noone else had.

Comment: Yeah, all of these are also valid options. Personally, I would make renaming `i` and `j` to something meaningful the the highest priority; beyond that, just pick a style and be consistent throughout your codebase.

Comment: It does pass PEP8 but do you really want your entire codebase to look like that? I've updated my answer with how I would reformat this code, have a peek. It not only passes pep8, but is even understandable by lay person (to a point), which is always a good sign.

Comment: @tzaman Thanks. I'd probably rename  as well. I admit I didn't even look at this code except for indenting/breaking.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul You mean whether I'd like my codebase to have this indenting? Yes, this is how I do it anyway, not just to answer this here. I didn't judge the code otherwise, only answered the question. I'd probably use better variable names, but I do like the list comprehension better than what you did. I find it clearer, and I don't work with lay persons.

Answer (score 2):

While I'm a fan of relaxing the strict-80-char limit, and (as mentioned in comment) so is [Raymond Hettinger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M) in this compelling talk from PyCon 2015, in this particular case, the cleanest thing might be to just split it into two lines:

```
valid_things = (i for i in j['collection'] if i and i['user_id'])
return [(i['user_id'], i['id']) for i in valid_things]
```

This way the "filtering" and "selection" logic are clearly separated and presented in a more readable way than jamming them together.

Another option for the functionally-inclined:

```
return map(itemgetter('user_id', 'id'), valid_things)
```

Comment: Somehow you've actually made the, already barely readable code, even less readable. Does it come with a manual?

Comment: It's no less readable than the original, and could be made better if `i` and `j` had meaningful names, which I can't supply as I have no context.

Comment: I have to disagree, because in the original one-liner at least it is easy to follow context, while here you first get some `valid_things` and then there is a line that only mention that it is using said `valid_things` at the end of it. So I guess I have to read this from right to left, but only on the second line, as this is only way for it to be at least readable.

Comment: This is very clear imo, it's a classic filter then map pattern. The op's code is also very readable and is a common map & filter pattern in python.

Comment: Agreed, I don't see how anyone would have a problem with this. Expecting the reader to keep context from the _immediate previous line_ is really not asking much.

Comment: Can you have a look at my answer? I'm confused because that's the smallest change and that's how I always do it, but nobody else suggested it. Is it frowned upon or something? (asking you since you're the top-rated member here)