# Python loop to create a two column layout

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, plotly-dash

I'm trying to make a two column loop in Python and Dash-Bootstrap-Component. The issue is Python related, I don't quite understand how to achieve this. 
I'm looping through a list of values. The layout should be multiple rows each with  two columns.

(Brevity code)

```
figs=[]
figs.append(dict(data=data, layout=layout)) # dash
body = dbc.Container(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            [                 
                dbc.Col(
                    [
                        html.H4('ES'+str(i)),
                        dcc.Graph(figure=figs[i]) 
                    ],
                    md=6
                ),
                dbc.Col(
                    [
                        html.H4('ES'+str(i+1)),
                        dcc.Graph(figure=figs[i+1]) # <- how to increment i here? This syntax 'figs[i+1]' throws an error.
                    ]
                )

            ]
        )       
       for i, value in enumerate(figs)
    ]
)
```

I need to display a graph `figs[i]` in column one, then increment the index to display the next graph in column two. `figs[i+1]` is not working and I'm not sure how to nest a for loop or do a while loop in this code. I've attached an image showing that the code works when using the same `figs[i]` for the two columns.

[image: multiple rows - two columns]

UPDATE: Thanks to erkandem's answer below, I was able to arrive at a conclusion which is posted here:

```
figs.append(dict(data=data, layout=layout))

body_py = [0] * len(figs)

for i, value in enumerate(figs):
    left = i
    right = i + 1 if i+1 < len(figs) else 0

    body_py[left] = figs[left]
    body_py[right] = figs[right]

body = dbc.Container(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(
                    [
                        html.H4('ES '+str(i)),
                        dcc.Graph(figure=body_py[i])
                    ],
                    md=6,
                )
                for i, value in enumerate(body_py)
            ]
        )
    ]
)

app.layout = html.Div([body])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

core issue boils down to `(i + i + 1)` instead of `i + 1` (ò.Ò really?)

```
figs = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
body = [0] * int((len(figs) / 2))


if len(figs) % 2 is not 0:
    print('appebnd a dummy figure')

for i in range(len(body)):
    # foreplay
    row = str(i)
    left = i + i
    right = (i + i + 1)
    print([row, left, right])

    # action
    body[i] = {row: [dict(h4=str(left), graph=figs[left]), dict(h4=str(right), graph=figs[right])]}

for row in body:
    print(row)
```

which prints:

```
{'0': [{'h4': '0', 'graph': 0}, {'h4': '1', 'graph': 1}]}
{'1': [{'h4': '2', 'graph': 2}, {'h4': '3', 'graph': 3}]}
{'2': [{'h4': '4', 'graph': 4}, {'h4': '5', 'graph': 5}]}
{'3': [{'h4': '6', 'graph': 6}, {'h4': '7', 'graph': 7}]}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, you put me in the right direction. I've posted my resulting code in the original post for the record.

Comment: been a pleasure. But I really should note that multi-line list apprehension as well as above usual indexing is unpythonic if not an anti pattern. Keyword: technical debt.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I'm not quite following. Yes, I'm coming from other languages, C++, PHP, etc, so I'd like to know.

Comment: In short: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30065598/10124294  Long version: I couldn't possibly tell it better than him. Was and is  a great resource for me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M

Comment: my bad: comprehensions. not apprehensions.