# Python multiple list comprehension does not work, how to do it correctly?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I try this:

```py
tmp = "one ; 1 \n two ; 2 \n three ; 3"
choices = [(x.strip(), y.strip()) 
           for choice in tmp.split("\n") 
           for x,y in choice.split(";")
           if choice.find(";") != -1]
```

The error message I get is this: `{ValueError} too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. Which I don't understand. If I modify the comprehension to this:

```py
>>> choices = [x 
               for choice in tmp.split("\n") 
               for x in choice.split(";")]
>>> choices
['one ', ' 1 ', ' two ', ' 2 ', ' three ', ' 3']
```

I see that the split is being performed correctly, just not assigned.

Basically I want this:

```py
>>> choices = [magical list comp using tmp variable]
>>> choices
[("one", "1"), ("two", "2"), ...etc ]
```

Does anyone know how?!

Comment: Please don't write code like this, it's hard for others to understand and with time it will be hard for you as well.

Comment: yeah great thanks, I please provide a better version or the actual answer. this does not help, and for loops seem clumsy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065551/pep-8-and-list-comprehension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
choices = [tuple(map(str.strip, choice.split(";"))) for choice in tmp.split("\n") if choice.find(";")]
print(choices)
```

**Output**

```
[('one', '1'), ('two', '2'), ('three', '3')]
```

Comment: this is probably exactly what I was looking for - technically. I get the point that this is pretty unmaintainable in time :) . I would consider the other Daniel's answer best for every day programming, and I will mark yours as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with you code is that your'e iterating over strings, but trying to unpack each string as a tuple of two elements.

let's consider the very first iteration of you're nested loop:

```
for choice in tmp.split("\n")
```

results in ['one ; 1 ']

and
`choice.split(";")`

results in ['one ']

so the line `for x,y in choice.split(";")`
will be evaluated as `x,y='one '` in the first iteration and will fail with `ValueError`

how about:

```
choices = []

for choice in tmp.split("\n"):
    choices.append(tuple([val.strip() for val in choice.split(";")]))

print(choices)
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answer gives an alternative solution, but I'll mention that the problem is that

```
for x,y in choice.split(";")
```

iterates the results returned by `choice.split(";")`.

Note that there's a difference between

```
for t in choice.split(";")  # t is each element of the list returned by split
```

and

```
t = choice.split(";")  # t is the whole list returned by split
```

It's clearer if you modify the comprehension a bit to give some debugging information:

```
>>> choices = [(t, len(t))
               for choice in tmp.split("\n") 
               for t in choice.split(";")]

>>> choices
[('one ', 4), (' 1 ', 3), (' two ', 5), (' 2 ', 3), (' three ', 7), (' 3', 2)]
```

---

Another solution would be to make use of [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

```
choices = [(x, y := choice.split(";"), (x.strip(), y.strip()))[1] 
           for choice in tmp.split("\n")
           if choice.find(";") != -1]
```

Untested since this only works in 3.8, and I don't have a 3.8 interpreter. It should work though.

Don't do this though. I'm only showing it because I think this is what you had in your head when you wrote `for x,y in choice.split(";")`.